# x clear icon appears only when the input has value - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please How can i get the clear x icon that appears only when i start writing in the input field using reactjs like the search input in google page https://www.google.com

```
import { XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';

export default function Search() {
  const inputElt = useRef(null);

  return (
    <form className='flex'>
     <input
        ref={inputElt}
        className='flex-grow focus:outline-none cursor-pointer'
        type='search'
    />
    <XIcon className='h-5' />
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditional render the icon based on the value of the input field. Maintain a state for the value using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook. onChange will trigger everytime you enter a value into the input field and set the state.

```
export default function Search() {
  const inputElt = useRef(null);
  const [value,setValue] = useState('')

  return (
    <form className='flex'>
     <input
        ref={inputElt}
        className='flex-grow focus:outline-none cursor-pointer'
        type='search'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) =>setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
    {value && <XIcon className='h-5' />}
)
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. It works, with only one change in your code is type='text' and not 'search' because search attribute by default gives the x close ( and i searched that it's not performed well in IE browser that's why i avoided type='search' in first place )

Comment: now, what about the clear effect, when clicking on the x icon i can clear the text written

Comment: Thank you again for your help

Comment: Is there an onClick available on the XIcon?

Comment: yes there is onClick()

Comment: clear the state on click of the icon, `onClick={() => setValue('')}`

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it reset the input field to nothing. I appreciate your help 

Comment: Don't mention it